# Ember export / import meaning with coffescipt

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

We have:

```
# app/components/my-component.coffee
`import Ember from 'ember'`

MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  tagName: 'div'

`export default MyComponent`
```

But in pure js it will be

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'div'
});
```

What all this import/export is about? Does `MyComponent` be named same as file or I can use whatever named var instead of it? Will I than need to use `import MyComponent` if I named it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this way because coffeescript doesn't have syntax for the `import` and `export` statements in es6.

In `ember-cli` each file is a es6 module. So whatever variables you declare within your module will only exist there. By convention the name of the exported component in your ember app will be `MyComponent` because the filename is `my-component.js`

But in your file you could just as well have given the variable a completely different name.

If you import this file somewhere else you can name it whatever you want there like this:

```
import Bananas from `components\my-component.js`
```

`Bananas` will now contain the `default` exported thing from `my-component.js`